# registration form validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Im partly there but it would be helpful if any of you guys could send the entire code .

1) Create a form with the below given fields and validate the same using javascript or jquery.

- Name : Text box- mandatory
- Gender : Radio Button
- Age : Text box - Accept Number only - (check for valid Age criteria)
- Email : Text box -  should be in format example@gmail.com
- Website : Text box -  should be in format http://www.example.com
- Country : Select box with 10 countries
- Mobile :  Text box - should be a 10 digit number - Display this field only after the user selects a country
- Social Media Accounts : Facebook, Google, Twitter (3 checkboxes) - Display Social media section only if selected Country is India
- I agree the Terms and Conditions - Checkbox

All fields are mandatory and show error messages for all fields(if not valid)
Only allow to submit form after checking the 'I agree' checkbox.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: im some where there for all but my social media option is not getting relied on the Country as India .

Comment: $("#social").hide() ;
// $("#hide").click(function(){
//     $("social").hide();
// });
// var country = document.getElementByName("country")[0].value;
// if (country.value == "India") {
//     $("#show").click(function(){
//     $("social").show();
// });
// }

Comment: see this plugin https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: <select class="country" id = "country">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option value="usa">United States</option>
                    <option value="india">India</option>
                    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                    <option value="uae">United Arab Emirates</option>

Comment: insert your tried code in question section

Comment: Could you send me the code for this as a solution

Comment: you post what you tried, then we find the issues and you fix them. It feels you are asking us to do your work here.

Comment: I would but it is too long

Comment: I shall post the entire thing as a comment.Im basically new to it so I shall post the html content first as a form_value.html page

Comment: I think there is no need for Javascript or Jquery... Html5 has 'Pattern attribute' which can do any form validation, you just need to know how. This will work for you. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: Jerin, edit your post to update it with the html content. Or alternatively use a service like pastebin or jsfiddle then link to it.

Comment: Actually the task is based for javascript or jquery understanding only so I preferred to use that .

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>

    <title>Get Values Of Form Elements Using jQuery</title>

  <!-- Include CSS File Here -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="form_value.css"/>
 <!-- Include JS File Here -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="form_value.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#social").hide() ;
 // $("#hide").click(function(){
  // $("social").hide();
  // });
  // var country = document.getElementByName("country")[0].value;
  // if (country.value == "India") {
  //     $("#show").click(function(){
    //     $("social").show();
    // });
   // }


  if (!(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/).test(document.email_id.value)) {
                alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
                return (false)
            }
       });

  </script>

  </head>

 <body onload="disableSubmit()">

 <div class="container">
 <div class="main">
 <h2>Get Values Of Form Elements Using jQuery</h2>
 <form action="">
 <!-- Text -->
 <br>
 <br>
 <label>Name :</label>
 <input type="text" id="text" name="name" value=""required/><br>


 <!-- Radio Button -->
 <br><br><br>
 <label>Gender:</label>
 <input type="radio" name="male" value="Male">Male
 <input type="radio" name="female" value="Female">Female

 <br><br>
 <!-- Textarea -->
 <label>Email :</label>
 <input type="text" id="Email" value="" id="Email"/>
  <br>


 <br><br>
   Age: <input type="text" id="Age" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" />
  <span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Input digits (0 -  9)</span>


 <br><br>
 <label> Website:</label>
 <input type="text" id="text" value="" name = "Website" id="website" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function validate() {
    if(Website.value.length==0)
   {
    document.getElementById("Website").innerHTML="Should be in the format     http://www.example.com ";
   }
       }
    </script>

   <br><br>

  <label>Country:</label>
   <select class="country" id = "country">
                <option>Select</option>
                <option value="usa">United States</option>
                <option value="india">India</option>
                <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="uae">United Arab Emirates</option>
                <option value="germany">Germany</option>
                <option value="france">France</option>
                <option value="netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                <option value="yemen">Yemen</option>
                <option value="pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                <option value="russia">Russia</option>

            </select>

            <br><br>

      <label>Mobile:</label>     
      <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" onkeypress="phoneno()"   maxlength="10">
       <script type="text/javascript">        
       function phoneno(){          
        $('#phone').keypress(function(e) {
            var a = [];
            var k = e.which;

            for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
                a.push(i);

            if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0))
                e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
   </script>

       <br><br>
        <div id = "social" >
       <p>Social Media Accounts.</p>  <input type="checkbox"   id="Facebook"   value="Facebook"><label for="Facebook"> Facebook</label><br>  <input type="checkbox" id="Google" value="Google"><label for="Google"> CSS</label><br>  <input type="checkbox" id="Twitter" value="Twitter"><label for="Twitter"> Twitter</label><br>
   </div>


     <br>
     <br>

     <script>
     function disableSubmit() {
     document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
     }

     function activateButton(element) {

     if(element.checked) {
      document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
      }
      else  {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
     }

      }
   </script>
   <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms"     onchange="activateButton(this)">  I Agree Terms & Coditions
        <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
    </script>
     </form>
    </div>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     this is my js page content form_value.js



       $(document).ready(function() {
       // Function to get input value.
       $('#text_value').click(function() {
        var text_value = $("#text").val();
        if(text_value=='') {
        alert("Enter Some Text In Input Field");
         }else{
        alert(text_value);
         }
         });


        // Funtion to get checked radio's value.
        $('#gender_value').click(function() {
         $('#result').empty();
         var value = $("form input[type='gender']:checked").val();
         if($("form input[type='gender']").is(':checked')) {
          $('#result').append("Checked Radio Button Value is :<span> "+             value +" </span>");
       }else{
       alert(" Please Select any Option ");
        }
       });
     // Get value Onchange radio function.
       $('input:gender').change(function(){
      var value = $("form input[type='gender']:checked").val();
      alert("Value of Changed Radio is : " +value);
          });
      // Funtion to reset or clear selection.
      $('#radio_reset').click(function() {
       $('#result').empty();
      $("input:radio").attr("checked", false);
          });



        $('#Email').click(function() {
       function validate(Email) {

        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-    z]{2,4})$/;
        //var address = document.getElementById[email].value;
        if (reg.test(email) == false) 
        {
            alert('Should be in the format example@gmail.com');
            return (false);
        }
         }

          });
          });

      $("#Age").click(function() {
            var specialKeys = new Array();
             specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
             function IsNumeric(e) {
             var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
                var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) ||         specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
             document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ?  "none" : "inline";
        return ret;
            }
            function handleChange(input) {
           if (input.value < 0) input.value = 0;
            if (input.value > 100) input.value = 100;
             }
             });


        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script> function validateForm() {
var name = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
var gender = document.forms["myForm"]["gender"].value;
var age = document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
var a = parseInt(age);
var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var url = document.forms["myForm"]["website"].value;
var country = document.forms["myForm"]["country"].value;
var mobileCountry = document.forms["myForm"]["mobileCountry"].value;
var mcLength = mobileCountry.length;



if (name == "") {
    alert("Name Field is mandatory");
     return false;
}
if (gender != "male" && gender != "female") {
    alert("Atleast one Gender has to be chosen");
     return false;
}
if(isNaN(a)){
    alert("Age is compulsory and must be a number");
     return false;
}

if(email == ""){
    alert("Email address is required");
}
else if(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)){

} else{
    alert("Email address entered is invalid");
     return false;
}
if(/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/.test(url)){

} else{
    alert("Website url entered is invalid");
     return false;
}
if(country != "choose"){
        document.getElementById("mc").style.display = "block";
} else{
        document.getElementById("mc").style.display = "none";
}

if(mcLength != 10){
        alert("Number must be ten digits");
        return false;
}

 } function displaySocial(){        var social = 
document.getElementById("social");
    var mc = document.getElementById("mobileCountry");

    var country = document.getElementById("country");
    var selectedValue = country.options[country.selectedIndex].value;
if (selectedValue != "choose")    {
   if(selectedValue == "india"){
    if(social.style.display = "none"){
        social.style.display = "block";
    } else{
        social.style.display = "none";
    }    } else{
    social.style.display = "none";    }

if(mc.style.display = "none"){

    mc.style.display = "block";
        } else{
    mc.style.display = "none";    }    } else{
    mc.style.display = "none";    }

} </script> </head> <body> <form name="myForm" action="/action_page_post.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"> Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br> Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender"> Female <br> age: <input type="text" name="age"><br> email: <input type="text" name="email"><br> website: <input type="text" name="website"><br> country: <select type="text" name="country" id="country"  onclick="displaySocial()"><option value="choose">--choose--</option><option value="usa">USA</option><option value="uk">UK</option><option value="ng">Nigeria</option><option value="india">India</option></select><br> <span id="mobileCountry" style="display: none;">mobile country: <input type="text" name="mobileCountry"><br></span> <span id="social" style="display: none;">Social Media: <input type="radio" name="gender"> Facebook <input type="radio" name="gender"> Google <input type="radio" name="gender"> Twitter</span> <br> <p> <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form> <p id="error"></p> </body> </html>
```

Comment: preview mie and use it to understand what you need... I did everything you wanted on it

Comment: good thanks Peter .Its working fine now. Would you be also having the code for Only allowing  to submit form after checking the 'I agree' checkbox.